# Javascript - get one function to run after another

Tags: javascript

I have a function that runs when a click event happens on a button - first(). Inside it populates a dictionary, and second() uses those values in the dictionary. I want second() to run after that dictionary has been populated. I have tried to put second() in a callback inside first() but it runs synchronously, meaning, (i think), the dictionarys are still empty when it starts the second function. I think that I need first to return a promise, or get second function to await the finish of first function, but I cannot figure out how. Any guidance is appreciated. Also I want to do this without JQuery (Ideally).

```
function first(){
  populateDict()
}

function second(){
  loopThroughDict()
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the bit about providing a [mcve].

Comment: async await will help here

Comment: Im not looking for an exact fix just a generic idea of how you would go about this

Comment: generic idea is to make the callback functions asynchronous, so it waits for the first function to populate the data and runs the "second" function only after that

Comment: Taking a step back, looking at what's happening, in javascript in the browser it tends to "timeout" long running commands so that they don't block the whole browser tab. This doesn't mean that computationally heavy tasks aren't possible, but they need to be handled accordingly. Callbacks and promises are good ways to guarantee execution order, and there are low level and synchronous style alternatives too, cf. [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API](Web workers), [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator](generators).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand async await, you can refer to this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Here `second()` function will be called only after `populateDict()` returns something

```
async function first(){
  await populateDict();
  second();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put the **callback** inside the `populateDict()` function.

```
function populateDict(second){
    //do some stuff to populate dictionary
    second()
}
```

and now call the populate dict with callback function in `first()`

```
function second(){
    iterateThroughDict()
}
function first(){
    populateDict(second)
}
```

I hope this will help you :)